# how to bind dataview to the treeview?

Tags: c#, winforms, treeview, datasource, dataview

I'm having a dataview which is collection of id & name. And i want  to bind that dataview to the treeview control in the form of hirarchy. And i want to show the name field as the display text on the node & i want to bind id as a value member to the tree node.

IS it possible? If yes then how to do this?

thanks..

Answer (score 0):

This snippet will display a dataview in a tree, where each row is a new node with children having column names followed by the field data for that column in the row:

```
var datasource = myDataView.ToTable();

treeView.BeginUpdate();

// Iterate throght the DataRow Collection
foreach (DataRow Row in datasource.Rows)
{
    TreeNode Node = treeView.Nodes.Add("Node for "+ Row.Field<string>("ColumnNameForNode"));

    if (Node != null)
    {
        int iCol = 0;

        foreach (var item in Row.ItemArray)
        {
            string itemString = item as string;
            if (itemString != null && itemString.Length > 0)
            {
                Node.Nodes.Add(datasource.Columns[iCol].ColumnName + " - " + itemString);
            }

            iCol++;
        }
    }                       
}

treeView.EndUpdate();
```